# One autherization method call for all users

Tags: gatling

I have a problem with setting up specific scnario in gatling.

I want to call my api to get authorization cookie, and then start the main scenario. I want to authorize only once, save the response, and then, for example, run test for 500 users for 30 minutes using the same auth cookie.

Is it possible to set up it like this? I'm not sure if it is possible using before hook.

I was searching for answer to this question, but I've found nothing. It would be great if I get some advices

Comment: Are you sure sure that you want to simulate 500 users all connecting with the same credentials ? Will your users in production all share the same login and password ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've created many scenarios for stress testing my website and I also want to check this scenario (remove the bottleneck, which is authorization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if anybody needs answer to this question besides me, but I'll post what I had to do, to achieve my goal :)

I simply made post to authentication method before the scenario. I used scalaj-http library.

I saved a response in a varable and after this request was completed I run my scenario with passed variable